# Bottle debug toolbar

Tags: python, bottle

Im trying to setup bottle debug toolbar but get the following error...

todo.py

```
import sqlite3
import bottle
from bottle_debugtoolbar import DebugToolbarPlugin
from bottle import route, run, debug, template, request, error, PasteServer

config = {'DEBUG_TB_ENABLED': True,
          'DEBUG_TB_INTERCEPT_REDIRECTS':True
                }

plugin = DebugToolbarPlugin(config)
bottle.install(plugin)
```

Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bottle.py", line 862, in _handle
    return route.call(**args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bottle.py", line 1727, in wrapper
    rv = callback(*a, **ka)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bottle_debugtoolbar/__init__.py", line 75, in wrapper
    return self.process_response(content)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bottle_debugtoolbar/__init__.py", line 135, in process_response
    and bottle.response.headers['content-type'].startswith('text/html')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bottle.py", line 1930, in __getitem__
    def __getitem__(self, key): return self.dict[_hkey(key)][-1]
KeyError: 'Content-Type'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bottle-debugtoolbar` makes an [assumption](https://github.com/sramana/bottle-debugtoolbar/blob/master/bottle_debugtoolbar/__init__.py#L135) that `Content-type` response header is set.

Just set the response content-type using [bottle.response](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/api.html#bottle.response):

```
from bottle import response
...

@bottle.route('/')
def index():
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'
    ...
```

UPD:

Here's a simple working example:

```
import bottle
from bottle_debugtoolbar import DebugToolbarPlugin
from bottle import response


config = {
    'DEBUG_TB_ENABLED': True,
    'DEBUG_TB_INTERCEPT_REDIRECTS': True,
}
plugin = DebugToolbarPlugin(config)
bottle.install(plugin)


@bottle.route('/')
def guestbook_index():
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'
    return '<html><body>Hello, world</body></html>'

bottle.debug(True)
bottle.run(host='localhost', port=8082)
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: :Thanks...it worked..but now I dont see the tool bar?

Comment: @user1050619 hm, check out the `UPD` section of the answer. This is what I've used for testing.

Comment: Thanks much..It worked.. I did not had the <body> tag within my html page...Once I added, I see it being displayed...

Comment: Everything looks good but I dont see the list of sqls being executed..Im sure the django debug toolbar has a panels for sqls being executed..How do I enable it?

Comment: @user1050619 I bet it doesn't support sql panels.

Comment: @user1050619 see how it's done [here](https://github.com/sramana/bottle-debugtoolbar/blob/c959f765f525a1bd8456313c586c7f013cd52a86/bottle_debugtoolbar/__init__.py#L11).